# How to get Date in the below Format "dd MMM, yyyy z"

Tags: java

How to make the date to have a **GMT** offset [like mentioned here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.lang.*;

class TFTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy z");
        Date dt = new Date();
        System.out.println("\n\n\nparsed date:"+sdf.format(dt)+"\n\n");
    }
}
```

the above program outputs the value as
parsed date:**02 Aug, 2016 IST**.

But I want the value to be parsed date:**02 Aug, 2016 GMT +05:30**

How to get in the specified format ..?

Comment: Possibly something like `dd MMM, yyyy 'GMT'X`.

Comment: @assylias can i get the above with "z" as they have given this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that should work is `dd MMM, yyyy 'GMT' XXX` indeed X is the timezone in [ISO 8601](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone) which seems to be what you are looking for.

**Output:**

```
parsed date:02 Aug, 2016 GMT +05:30
```

Comment: Is there a way with "z" itself to get the above result ..? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone

Comment: No because of this "Time zones are interpreted as text if they have names" which is the case here its name is IST

Comment: z Time zone General time zone Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00   find this row in the same page... does this say it can be done using "z" itself ...?

Comment: this only means that it depends on the timezone id set if the timezone id is PST, it will print PST but if it is GMT-08:00, it will print GMT-08:00. In your case the timezone id is IST so it prints IST if you want to have the GMT offset value whatever the timezone id you have to use X instead of z

Answer (score 1):

Try, for more documentation visit [simpledateformat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
"dd MMM, yyyy 'GTM' XXX"

Answer (score 0):

This pattern "dd MMM, yyyy z ZZZZ" will print in the given format

*Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy z ZZZZ")*;

Result like :
**02 Aug, 2016 GMT +0000**